# Diferencia entre fecha actual y fecha posterior, minutos tarde, tracking

Tags: java, android, datetime

Quiero calcular la diferencia en minutos entre una fecha y otra, sin embargo cuando esta diferencia es mayor a 45, quiero que diga que va "x minutos tarde", si pasan "y" minuto(s) debería de mostrar: "x+y minutos tarde"
Actualmente tengo esto, funciona perfectamente cuando la fecha actual es menor a la fecha que debe cumplirse:

```
 Date fechaactual = new Date();
    long diff = trackingfecha.getTime() - fechaactual.getTime();
    long diferenciaminutos = diff / (60 * 1000);
    RunneableUpdateUI run = new RunneableUpdateUI();
    if(diffMinutes < 45.0) {
        if(diffMinutes >= 0) {
            //Se muestran los minutos restantes para llegar a la fecha trackingfecha 
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            buffer.append("te quedan ");
            String minutes = String.format("%02d", diffMinutes);
            buffer.append(minutes);
            buffer.append(" min");
            run.toUpdateValue = buffer.toString();
        } else {
           //Actualmente aqui es el problema, siempre que hago la operación muestra números completamente incongruentes, como 200 minutos tarde. Incluso cuando la diferencia es de solamente 60 minutos.
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String minutes = String.format("%02d", Math.abs(diffMinutes));
            buffer.append(minutes);
            buffer.append(" min tarde");
            run.toUpdateValue = buffer.toString();
        }
        timerHandler.post(run);
    }
```

Quiero calcular el tiempo que le falta para llegar a una fecha especifica y si se pasa de esta fecha especifica, mostrar que tan tarde va.

Comment: Qué es lo que exactamente quieres hacer?

Comment: Quiero calcular el tiempo que le falta para llegar a una fecha especifica y si se pasa de este tiempo, mostrar que tan tarde va.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código se ve bien, lo que no entiendo es donde sacas la variable `diffMinutes` si anteriormente calculas `diferenciaminutos.

```
    RunneableUpdateUI run = new RunneableUpdateUI();
    if(Math.abs(diferenciaminutos) < 45 ) { // muestra valores solamente cuando la diferencia es menos de 45 min
        if(diferenciaminutos >= 0) {
            //Se muestran los minutos restantes para llegar a la fecha trackingfecha 
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            buffer.append("te quedan ");
            String minutes = String.format("%02d", diferenciaminutos);
            buffer.append(minutes);
            buffer.append(" min");
            run.toUpdateValue = buffer.toString();
        } else {
           //Actualmente aqui es el problema, siempre que hago la operación muestra números completamente incongruentes, como 200 minutos tarde. Incluso cuando la diferencia es de solamente 60 minutos.
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String minutes = String.format("%02d", -diferenciaminutos); // negativo, porque < 0
            buffer.append(minutes);
            buffer.append(" min tarde");
            run.toUpdateValue = buffer.toString();
        }
```

Comment: Perdon, error de dedo, son la misma variable.

Comment: ok, puedes corregir tu código? si lo compruebo me da resultados correctos, así revisa que el código de tu pregunta esta el mismo que usas para que se puede reconstruir tu error ;)